# How do I migrate a NUnit configuration file to MSTest?

Tags: unit-testing, nunit, mstest

I would like to migrate all my unit tests from NUnit to MSTest. In the solution I have a NUnit configuration file, which looks like this:

```
<NUnitProject>
    <Settings activeconfig="Web">
    <Config name="Web" appbase="Web" configfile="web.config" binpathtype="Auto">
        <assembly path="bin\Product.NUnit.ComponentA.dll"/>
        <assembly path="bin\Product.NUnit.ComponentB.dll"/>
        <assembly path="bin\Product.NUnit.ComponentC.dll"/>
    </Config>
</NUnitProject>
```

How could I do that in MSTest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use MSBuild to execute a "MSTest-Task"...
Have a look here: *[MSTest task for MSBuild](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/ndobkin/archive/2007/12/16/mstest-task-for-msbuild.aspx)*